# How do I change Vue JS 2 router mode from hash to history?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I'm new to VueJS and created a project with hash routing. Is there a way to change it to history mode (v2.x)?

I tried the following:

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [...]
})
```

and

```
const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(),
  routes
})
```

But they won't work. The fisrt one just doesn't do anything, and the second one just triggers some warnings on the CLI.

```
WARNING  Compiled with 2 warnings                                                                               9:14:51
 warning  in ./src/router/index.js

export 'createRouter' (imported as 'createRouter') was not found in 'vue-router' (possible exports: NavigationFailureType, RouterLink, RouterView, START_LOCATION, default, isNavigationFailure, version)

 warning  in ./src/router/index.js

export 'createWebHistory' (imported as 'createWebHistory') was not found in 'vue-router' (possible exports: NavigationFailureType, RouterLink, RouterView, START_LOCATION, default, isNavigationFailure, version)
```

Comment: The first way you did it is the way to do it in Vue 2. What is not working? Have you made sure your server configuration can [deal with it](https://v3.router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#html5-history-mode)?

Comment: @Yitz You're right. I had a typo in my web.config file. That solved my problem.